# mysql2 adapter issues in installing Redmine on Fedora 17

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I was trying to install `Redmine` on `Fedora 17`, following  [this](http://www.redmine.org/issues/11071)

**Until this step:**

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

**It throws an error saying:**

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2)
/var/www/redmine/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/var/www/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

**which is weird, because I have already installed mysql2 with bundle:**

```
bundle show
...
* mysql2 (0.3.11)//***which is right in the bundle show list***
...
```

**my database.yml is like:**

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: 123456
  encoding: utf8
```

others my be involved

```
    ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [i386-linux]
    Rails 3.2.8                                          
    gem 1.8.24
    mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.28, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1
    Redmine 2.1.3
```

I have found some related questions by google, like:http://www.redmine.org/issues/11071#note-4
And I do as they said, adding symlink

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib /usr/share/ruby/mysql2
```

**Then exactly as posted in the page:**

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::REMEMBER_OPTIONS
```

I tried to do what is posted in #6 but it didn't work for me.
Is this the right way to solve my problem, and what should I do with the second bug.

Comment: Might ``bundle exec`` be the issue?

Comment: what do you mean? Am I suppose to execute this command in Terminal?

Comment: Gems can be installed in a gemset on your system, or they can be installed in the myapp/vendor/cache folder. When using a Capistrano/Bundler deploy setup, the gems are installed in myapp/vendor/cache and are executable by prepending commands with `bundle exec`. Therefore, if you are SSHing into your server and running the command there, you should prepend commands with bundle exec.

Comment: thks but neither can I make it right not SSHing but in localhost, I have found the reason for this. Seems like the Fedora bundle is somewhere different, because I can go through it by 1.gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx 2.yum install rubygem-bundler and then reinstall the gems by bundle install, weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> add gem "minitest" into Gemfile
> gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
> yum erase rubygem-activesupport-3.0.11-5.fc17.noarch
> yum install rubygem-bundler
> bundle install
> then other steps, this works!!
```

for details, please refer to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=829209#c35)
thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Add `gem 'mysql2'` in your gemfile and run `bundle install` and then do `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

Comment: Of course the app's Gemfile has this including in it.~see my answer, I have solved this problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Fedora's ruby, try:

`yum install ruby-mysql`

If you're using RVM or any other similar tool, install mysql's development packages, and then reinstall the ruby mysql gem.

`yum install mysql-devel`

Comment: actually I have get it through by :1.gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx 2.yum install rubygem-bundler and then reinstall the gems by bundle install, weird..