# Problems with redmine installing step 5. rake generate_secret_token

Tags: mysql, ruby, rake, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on my fedora machine and I have been following the official wiki to install it, I have gotten up to step 5 when I am asked to run the

*rake generate_secret_token*

command, however when I do I get this error

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
/home/usera/redmine-2.3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/usera/redmine-2.3/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

with --trace

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/home/usera/redmine-2.3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/usera/redmine-2.3/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

I am running the command as root. This is the guide I used http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the necessary native libraries for mysql2 adaptor ?
You can check:
[mysql2 adapter issues in installing Redmine on Fedora 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465678/mysql2-adapter-issues-in-installing-redmine-on-fedora-17)